# Convert sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey to java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, private-key

how to convert `sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey`  from `java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey` ?

**My code snippet:**

```
RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey)(pvtKey);
```

where **pvtKey** is `java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey type.`

**this line gives me exception :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey cannot be cast to java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey
```

Comment: This does not make sense you can not "convert" the key. But you can typecast it to `java.security.PrivateKey`- this is enough for working with it.

Comment: Robert u should go for solving linguistic problems rather .. best of luck